# Mule Message Redelivery

Tags: message, mule, endpoint, connector

Does anyone know what is the difference between maxRedelivery attribute on a connector and defining idempotent-redelivery-policy on an endpoint? Are they both same?

One difference I know is in idempotent-redelivery-policy you can define dead-letter-queue to direct error messages on error queue. What happens when you define maxRedelivery on a connector? After max attempts is message discarded?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The maxRedelivery applies only for the jms transports and it is maintained for backwards compatibility. If the maxRedelivery threshold is overcome a [MessageRedeliveredException](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/exception/MessageRedeliveredException.html) is thrown and it's up to your configuration to handle it.

If you need a more configurable pattern I'd recommend you to use idempotent-redelivery-policy since it can be configured within many transports and offer you more options